# Adding characters like '☯' in char[][] will push everything to the right

Tags: arrays, char, special-characters

I'm doing a tic-tac-toe game and I want to add fancy characters like '☯' for example.
When I'm adding (`arr[i][j]='☯';`) the char there are no errors or anything, everything working properly.
When I print out the array I can see that everything is being pushed to the right. How can I fix that?
Thanks.

the picture shows that everything is pushed:
[image: the picture shows that everything is pushed]

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the *fancy characters* occupy two positions in a screen line (*double width*). To account for that, print one space less after such a character.